# Filter "wp_mail" - How to distinguish between a WordPress system email and a plugin email?

Tags: email, wp-mail

Using the `wp_mail` filter I add a "Reply-To" to the header with my email address, so clients can reply directly to the email to contact me if there's any issues. I only want this on WordPress "system" emails, like emails for new accounts, password resets, etc. If a plugin sends an email using `wp_mail()` I don't want to set the Reply To address. Is there some way to know when it's WordPress core sending an email rather than a plugin?

Here's what I'm using to set the Reply-To (from a custom class):

```
public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'wp_mail', array( $this, 'setReplyTo' ), PHP_INT_MAX );
}

public function setReplyTo( array $args ) : array
{
    $reply_to = 'Reply-To: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>';
    
    if ( ! empty( $args['headers'] ) ) {
        if ( ! is_array( $args['headers'] ) ) {
            $args['headers'] = array_filter( explode( "\n", str_replace( "\r\n", "\n", $args['headers'] ) ) );
        }
        // Remove existing Reply-To headers
        $args['headers'] = array_filter( $args['headers'], function( $header ) {
            return strpos( strtolower( $header ), 'reply-to' ) !== 0;
        } );
    }
    else {
        $args['headers'] = [];
    }

    $args['headers'][] = $reply_to;

    return $args;
}
```

Nothing in the `$args` parameter appears to contains anything I can use to accomplish this. Hopefully there's some way to know what is initiating the emails. Thanks!

Comment: WP doesn't differentiate "system" emails, but, perhaps you can filter based on the recipient? E.g. system emails are going to be sent to very specific people by vanilla WP sites, mainly site administrators. Heuristics are the closest you'll get but wether that's feasible depends on the kinds of emails your plugins are sending out. Another avenue to explore is not to use this filter to do that check, but to perform the check somewhere else, e.g. in the lost password filter and set a flag which you then look for in this filter

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks! I was thinking of checking if the recipient email is the administrator or one of the WordPress users, which could work, but obviously if a WordPress user/admin is the recipient of a non-system email then it won't work. That's not a big deal though. I really like the idea about hooking into the various filters and setting a flag. I'm going to explore that some more. Thanks again!

Comment: Few years ago I suggested using keywords/namespaces in wp_mail here https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53829 No news but welcome to lobby for it there and take the work further.

Comment: @birgire That would be an excellent solution. I added a comment on there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @birgire that [#53829-core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53829) would be the ideal way to do this. If you need a hack that works in the meantime, though, then you can examine the filenames in the call stack.

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', 'modify_system_emails' );

function modify_system_emails( array $attributes ) : array {
    $wp_mail_caller = get_wp_mail_caller();

    if ( is_core_file( $wp_mail_caller['file'] ) ) {
        $attributes['subject'] .= ' -- (system)';
    }

    return $attributes;
}

function get_wp_mail_caller() : array {
    $backtrace = debug_backtrace( DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS );

    foreach ( $backtrace as $call ) {
        if ( 'wp_mail' === $call['function'] ) {
            return $call;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception( "`wp_mail()` wasn't found in the backtrace." );
}

function is_core_file( string $filename ) : bool {
    $relative_path = str_replace( ABSPATH, '', $filename );
    $parts         = explode( '/', $relative_path );

    if ( in_array( $parts[0], [ 'wp-admin', 'wp-includes' ], true ) ) {
        return true;
    } elseif ( preg_match( '#^wp-.*\.php$#', $parts[0] ) ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

You can test that with some code like:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    wp_mail( 'foo@example.com', 'not a system email', 'nosirree' ); // This won't modify the subject.
    wp_site_admin_email_change_notification( 'foo@example.org', 'bar@example.org', 'foo' ); // This will modify the subject.
} );
```

Comment: That's actually a really cool solution. It's hack-ish for sure but it's a solid approach. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)